# OS X's FileVault password screen extremely unresponsive

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, filevault

I have a FileVault-protected MacBook with OS X 10.11.6 installed alongside a BootCamp Windows 10 partition.

Lately, whenever I reboot the MacBook and allow it to automatically boot into the OS X operating system, the FileVault password screen is **extremely** unresponsive. I can type in the password, but have to wait from 10 to 15 seconds after typing each character to allow the system to catch up with my typing.

Besides these symptoms, the mouse pointer and the caps lock on/off light are equally very slow to respond / catch up.

Both operating systems have their latest & greatest updates.

Any clues about this annoying behaviour and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is normal on FileVault enabled MacBook. There is about 10 seconds latency on my late 2013 rMBP. I suggest to wait a bit more time as the problem improved dramatically two weeks later after I turned it on.

Comment: I have FileVault enabled on this Mac for a few months now, and this behaviour only started lately.